# Can this participle clause have different functions?

Tags: meaning

Participle clauses usually show things like event order, time, cause and effect. I wonder if the following past participle clause can mean different things.

> Filmed inside, the footage was too dark to use.

Most commonly it means "because it was filmed inside." But can it also mean "after it was filmed inside?"

Or does the sentence have to be phrased in this way for it to imply event order?

> Filmed inside, the footage **became** too dark to use.

Comment: What would the actual difference in meaning be?  You can't see the footage *before* it is filmed!

Comment: @stangdon Perhaps it's a bad example. But is it possible for a clause like this to be interpreted differently and have more distinct meanings?

Comment: No, a clause like that always should refer to what comes next. But people often misplace them: Filmed inside, it was hard to see the footage.

Comment: If it was filmed using actual film  and not digitally, it could darken.

Comment: The first: the salient interpretation is that as a consequence of filming inside, where the lighting may have been poor, the footage was too dark to use. There is nothing to suggest that the footage deteriorated after filming. Note that the comma after the clause "filmed inside" marks it as a supplementary adjunct, not a modifying one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A misplaced participle clause:

> Definition: A participial phrase is misplaced if it seems to modify a
> word other than the one the writer intended to modify. It is often
> added to a sentence as an afterthought. The idea was clear in the
> author's mind, but it didn't translate to the reader. Misplaced: **We
> got on the bus, soaked from the rain. (Was the bus soaked?) Better:
> Soaked from the rain, we got on the bus.**

[misplaced participial clause](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-9/verbals-and-phrases/lesson-4/misplaced-participial-phrases)

**The rule concerns what the clause modifies and not what the main verb of the sentence is.**

Filmed inside, the footage was too dark to use.

Filmed inside, the footage became too dark to use.

Both sentences are correct because "filmed inside" refers to the footage. If it became dark, the film is celluloid, not digital.